# Conditional display formats in R

Tags: r, format

In an R dataframe, is it possible to use numerical format so that

```
x <- c(155.395227, 11.16707, NA, 0.259722)
```

is displayed as:

```
 x <- c(155, 11, NA, 0.3)
```

I tried with prettyNum, but I'm not sure whether or not this is possible. In other words, if x < 1 then display 1 decimal point.

Comment: Perhaps `sub("\\.0+$", "", ifelse(x< 1, round(x, 1), as.integer(x)))`.  It is diffficult to store as a vector with numeric class and integer.  May be check `list` i.e. `lapply(as.list(x), function(y) if(y < 1 & !is.na(y)) round(y, 1) else as.integer(y))`  BTW are you looking for a character output or `numeric` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quick fix using the apply function:

```
x <- c(155.395227, 11.16707, NA, 0.259722)
x2 <- c(123.4, 4.5, 0.2, 3)
df <- data.frame(x, x2)

apply(df, 2, function(input){ ifelse(input<1, format(round(input, 1), 1), format(round(input, 0), 0))})
```

Not sure if you want the rounding or just a cutoff, works for both, just delete the round function within the format.

Answer (score 1):

If we need a character output, then after doing an `ifelse` remove the 0's after the `.`

```
sub("\\.0+$", "", ifelse(x< 1, round(x, 1), as.integer(x)))
#[1] "155" "11"  NA    "0.3"
```

---

But, if the objective is to store different class types, then store it as a `list`

```
lapply(as.list(x), function(y) if(y < 1 & !is.na(y)) round(y, 1) else as.integer(y))
#[[1]]
#[1] 155

#[[2]]
#[1] 11

#[[3]]
#[1] NA

#[[4]]
#[1] 0.3
```